# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, request-uri

I'm currently working on an existing project (java version: 1.7.0, using Spring MVC framework version: 3.1.4) where we only have located this `PathVariable` issue in only one URI of an specific controller class, and I would really appreciate if any of you have already faced this error and how did you fix/solve it? Thanks!

**Code** (extracted part of the java controller class):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/site/apps/{question}.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ServiceResponse moreUsers(
        @PathVariable("question") final Question question,
        @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) final String sort,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model)
```

**Error** output of our tomcat log (catalina.out file):

```
ERROR Error executing request: /site/apps/52440.json
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public com.project.infrastructure.service.ServiceResponse com.project.plugins.controllers.SiteAppController.moreUsers(com.project.models.node.Question,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Could not find @PathVariable [question] in @RequestMapping**
```

**What we've already researched:**

- followed *spring convention* for PathVariable annotation according to the specification doc (mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates),
- No other similar path has been found on the java project, that will maybe have a conflict *matching* within (/site/apps/{question-id})
- we've also logged the mapping and looks good, according to the *mappedPattern* value (located here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java#L755-L764)
- the interesting thing comes when calling *resolvePathVariable* spring method, since the "URI Template Variable Map" value is **null** (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java#L853-L854 and don't know why!

Comment: Is there any url patterns similar to this? And why your parameter type is `Question`?

Comment: `@PathVariable` should be a `String`,  not a  `Question`.

Comment: No, there isn't any url pattern similar to this, there is no duplicated URI on this project. It was originally coded by using a custom Question object that has and id field into it. But, in order to be sure this issue is not related with that, I already tested by replacing Question object by a Long object and also even by using a long primitive as well

Comment: According to spring doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates), a @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc. Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type or throws a TypeMismatchException if it fails to do so.

Comment: have you added <mvc:annotation-driven/> to your dispatcherServlet? @HernanA

Comment: Yes @TahirHussainMir, it has been already added. And if it's related with this, any PathVariable annotation shouldn't work on my java project, and that's not the case. Anyway thks for the reply.

Comment: what is question? @HernanA

Comment: Question is a model object that has several fields, and the important one named as id and type as Long.

Answer (score 0):

In your method handler try to use {question} pathVariable as int, assuming you have int questionid field in your Question JavaBean & try to construct Question JavaBean inside method handler..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/site/apps/{question}.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ServiceResponse moreUsers(
        @PathVariable("question") Integer question,
        @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) final String sort,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model){

Question Q=questionservice.getQuestion(question);

}
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I haven't tried with Integer, but I already tested by replacing Question object by a Long object, and also even by using a long primitive as well.